# Reference Another Worksheet in Excel Cell Formula through Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, vlookup

In an Access VBA module, I am copying a recordset to an Excel worksheet (DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet does not provide the needed color and formula formatting).

On one column range, in trying to apply an INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP in a c.Value or c.Formula, I cannot reference another worksheet within the same workbook I am working on. With every output from Access, Excel renders the #REF! error. However, when I copy and paste the formula from the VBA window into cell and drag down in Excel, it works perfectly! And when I change the worksheet's reference to same worksheet name, no #REF! error.

I know the issue is the worksheet instance of the Excel object. I tried to open another worksheet object (the xlInv object) and use the Excel's .Address function but it only points to the active worksheet's cell ranges. See my code below (both vlookup and index match does exactly same thing):

```
Public Function SendReq2Excel(strTQName As String, strSheetName As String)

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim ApXL, xlWBk, xlWsh, xlInv As Object
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim strPath, allsheet, mostsheet, subtotalcell, othersheet As String
Dim recordcount, avgprice, totalreq As Integer

On Error GoTo err_handler

strPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Requisition Form.xlsx"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTQName)
Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWBk = ApXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
ApXL.Visible = False

Set xlWsh = xlWBk.Worksheets(strSheetName)
Set xlInv = xlWBk.Worksheets("INVENTORY")

...

avgprice = 2
For Each c In xlWsh.Range("O2:O" & recordcount + 1)
    'c.Formula VLOOKUP(C" & avgprice & ", INVENTORY!$B$2:INVENTORY!$X$2000, 23, FALSE)
    c.Formula = "=INDEX(INVENTORY!$X$3:INVENTORY!$X$2000, MATCH(C" & avgprice & ", INVENTORY!$B$3:INVENTORY!$B$2000, 0))"
    avgprice = avgprice + 1
Next
```

Do I have to close one Excel worksheet object and open another but how can I interact with both worksheets at the same time? Do I have to Select the range of the other Excel worksheet prior to defining formula? Please help. Any suggestions is welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found my own error. I called the referenced worksheet after the active worksheet which used the formula. Hence, not being able to detect the corresponding worksheet, #REF! appeared in the cells. Simply re-ordering the worksheets fixed the error output.

So, the formula works correctly. MS Access can reference a different worksheet in a cell formula when outputting to Excel.